# sum of each user's payment using sakila table

Tags: mysql

How do you do the SQL query using sakila database in MySQL, finding the sum of each user's payment amount?

```
select customer_id, sum(amount)
from payment
group by customer_id;
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Do you have any errors this seems to be fine...

Comment: thanks very much. I have double check and discover typo. It is working now.